# Cypher query to search a phrase in all properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've encountered an interesting problem while trying to implement search in my `Neo4j` DB. I want to search a certain phrase (allowing also partial matches) in any of the node's properties. This has to be generic and work for all node types and labels, so I can't have a pre-defined list of properties to search.

In order to understand the problem, consider the famous Movie DB tutorial that comes bundled in Neo4j browser (`:play movie graph`): Let's say I want to search nodes with label `Movie` that have a property that starts with 'The'. My first idea was:

```
match (m:Movie)
where (any(prop in keys(m) where m[prop] starts with "The")) 
return m
```

This of course throws an error because one of the properties is a number and not a string. Using `toString` won't help me, because in my DB some of the properties are boolean, and booleans don't respond to `toString`.

My next attempt was with regex, which is also better for search because I can make it case insensitive and more robust in general. So I did this:

```
match (m:Movie)
where (any(prop in keys(m) where m[prop] =~ "(?i)The .*"))
return m
```

And it worked! I got all the movies that either their title or tagline start with 'The'. And there was much rejoicing.

But now comes the tricky part. My search also needs to provide negation of the search, i.e. all movies that *don't* have any property that starts with 'The'. I obviously tried:

```
match (m:Movie)
where NOT (any(prop in keys(m) where m[prop] =~ "(?i)The .*"))
return m
```

But this query returned an empty response. No error, just no results.

When trying to isolate the problem, I've realized that the query *does* work in the following cases:

1. If a node only has string properties (no numbers or booleans).
2. If I use exact matches instead of regex (`where NOT(any(prop in keys(m) where m[prop] = "Hoffa"))`).
3. If I search specific properties (`where NOT(any(prop in ['title','tagline'] where m[prop] =~ "(?i)The .*"))`)

It seems that only the combination of `not`, `any`, and regex breaks the query, and I'm lost in finding out why this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least in neo4j 3.0, the `STARTS WITH` syntax seems to work better for your scenario (but it is case sensitive):

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NONE(prop in keys(m) where TOSTRING(m[prop]) STARTS WITH "The ")
RETURN m;
```

Comment: As you can see in my question, I've considered this option, but since some of the properties are boolean, `toString` doesn't work for me

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using? It works for me in 3.0.

Comment: Yes! in 3.0.1 `tostring` also applies to booleans, so I can also use regex like I wanted.

Comment: This is essentially doing a full db scan. Is there an efficient way of doing this? maybe with indexing? I read about indexes but is it true that you need to specify a property on an index?

Comment: neo4j also supports "legacy indexes" -- also called [manual indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#indexing) -- and there are [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_manual_indexes) that make it possible to work with them from Cypher code. Legacy indexes take much more of an effort to use, but that might be necessary in some use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
NOT (ANY
```

try

```
(NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
match (m:Movie)
where (any(prop in keys(m) where m[prop] =~ '.*the.*'))
return m
```